# how to post indeterminate checkbox with php?

Tags: php, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes. checkbox1 is checked and checkbox2 is indeterminated.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="2">
```

then i post them to another php. i give them by this code:

```
foreach($_POST['checkboxes'] as $checkbox){
echo $checkbox;
}
```

but this code just give checkbox that is checked!

Comment: what you expect $_POST['checkboxes'] should contain?

Answer (score 2):

Give the checkboxes `value`s. Then you can tell which ones were checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the checkbox different values with the `value` attribute for every field. Then you have an value in your Post array and you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give values to your checkboxs

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="somthing1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="something2">
```

you can refer to this example : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_value